# Creating model from ado.net code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ado.net

Is there a way to create a model from an ado.net SqlDataReader? I would really prefer to use Asp.net MVC 5 coming from Ruby on Rails rather than Webforms, but I need a way to display the data from an existing database on the view. Or could I possibly do this without creating a model by handling this in the controller? I don't want to create a model based on column names in the table in case the table (or db schema) changes later on.

Answer (score 0):

Use Entity Framework`s DbContext.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to create fields for columns in the table, like here http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/adding-a-model

Answer (score 0):

Looking around, the normal solution would be to reverse-engineer the model from the database found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/671590/Reverse-Engineering-an-Existing-Database-in-your-A

Unfortunately, this is something that usually has to be done through Visual Studio, which I will not always have access to once the application is in production mode. If the schema changes, I would not be able to use the `Update Model from Database...` command in VS 2013. Therefore, I'll have to use Asp.net Web Forms for my Database-First application.